# Troubles getting stuff to bundle:

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Hello(sorry about that) all, I'm working on a code that will allow me to enter a number in a settings screen for an app widget. That will then we saved and stored as a variable to be used in the main app for which the widget was made. I'm wondering how I can bundle the number chosen and transfer it over to the app/widget to be run.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WWSettings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Context context = this;
    Button svBtn;
    AppWidgetManager awm;
    EditText userNum;
    TextView unOut;
    int awID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.widgetconfig);
        svBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnwidgetconfig);
        emsNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etwidgitconfig);
        emsOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unOut);
        svBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        //get widget info!
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        if(extras !=null){
            awID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }
        else{
            finish();
        }
        awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String e = userNum.getText().toString();
        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.unOut, "Your Number is set to" + e);
        Intent sparkintent = new Intent(this, startSpark.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, sparkintent, 0);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnwidgetconfig, pi);
        sparkintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        awm.updateAppWidget(awID, view);

        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Das Kat of the logz:

```
07-26 17:13:08.629: W/dalvikvm(1488): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lionsimage.com.this/lionsimage.com.this.startSpark}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at lionsimage.com.webb.startSpark.onCreate(startSpark.java:28)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-26 17:13:08.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You are getting a `NullPointerException` at line `28` of `startSpark.java`, which is in your `onCreate` method for `startSpark`. Could you post that line by itself?